# Issue with spread operator in LWC Salesforce for Sandbox Environment

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, debugging, bug

In the lookup component when am searching the name with (onchangesearchinput) by entering the value, here calling a method from server side class the data is returning from backend but it is not displaying in the UI.

In the below snippet we are getting the values is local variable i.e. dataoptions but when i am assigning this to the this.variable array but in the output of this is showing null array. could you please help me on this issue (urgent required)

```
                this.optionsTemp = [];
                let dataoptions = [];
                result.map(element=>{
                    this.optionsTemp = [...this.optionsTemp ,
                        {value: element.fieldValue, 
                        label: element.fieldLabel}]; 
                        
                    dataoptions= [...dataoptions ,
                        {value: element.fieldValue, 
                        label: element.fieldLabel}]; 
                   
                });
                console.log('dataoptions',dataoptions);             
                
                console.log('TestData',this.optionsTemp);   

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    this.optionsTemp = [...this.optionsTemp, {
                    value: result[i].fieldValue,
                    label: result[i].fieldLabel
                }]; 
    }
```

used this code as well, we are having issue only in qa and not in production, it is working fine in PROD.
Output
dataoptions
[image]

this.optionsTemp
[image]

Answer (score 2):

the map function returns an array of objects, instead of assigning values within the map, you should assign the result of the map to your variable as follows:

```
this.optionsTemp =  result.map(element=>{ return {value: element.fieldValue, 
                        label: element.fieldLabel}})
```

if you need to merge the result of the map with what is already in this.optionsTemp, you can use the spread operator to do so, and instead, assign what the map returns to another variable.

Ex:

```
const otherResults = result.map(element=>{ return {value: element.fieldValue, 
                            label: element.fieldLabel}})
this.optionsTemp = [...this.optionsTemp, ...otherResults]
```

don't confuse [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: replaced with above code , its not working

Comment: please update your post

Comment: I have checked with below snippet but its not showing any result.                                   
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++)                                                                                      
                  { this.optionsTemp = [...this.optionsTemp, { value: result[i].fieldValue, label: result[i].fieldLabel }]; }

Comment: ?? i dont see any for loop in your post, please update your original post

Comment: can you see the for loop now

Comment: can you please check as winter 22 update is happened in sandboxes, hence getting this issue